# Support library only using latest versions

Tags: android, gradle, android-support-library

About Android support library, since 25.0.1 has some bugs, so I want to use 7.24.1,
here's some of my gradle codes

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'
```

But I find the project still refers the latest version; the version number "v7:24.2.1" does not work.

I want use `7:24.2.1`, but when I click any Android support class, such as `RecyclerView`, it opens source code from `sdk\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support\recycler‌​view-v7\25.0.0\recyc‌​lerview-v7-25.0.0-so‌​urces.jar`

Comment: Explain more clearly about whats the matter?

Comment: the version number "v7:24.2.1" does not work. I want use 7:24.2.1,but when i click any android support class ,such as RecycleView, it opens source code from sdk\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support\recyclerview-v7\25.0.0\recyclerview-v7-25.0.0-sources.jar

Comment: Clean Project will do the trick I suppose

Answer (score 2):

Clean Project will do the trick. Furthermore consider to change `compileSdkVersion`to`24` and also install Android SDK Build-tools in Android SDK Manager.

As the latest version of the support library according to the support library changelog is `v7:25.0.1` and not `v7:24.2.1` modify your `build.gradle` to have `v7:25.0.1`:

```
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1"
```

However, if you really need `v7:24.2.1` then simply put:

```
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
```

You dont have to put the rest. They are already included as stated by cricket_007.

Comment: The design library includes v7 and recyclerview, and v7 includes v4. Only cardview and design are necessary... Anyways, the question clearly said that 24 sdk libraries aren't working

Comment: inserted your comment

Answer (score 0):

It turns out one of the depencencies include the android suppoert library25.0.0，
I solve it by downgrading the depencency library